# "now that a brace of more able-bodied men were coming home"

Tags: meaning

> now that a brace of more able-bodied men were coming home.

Brace doesn't make sence in this sentence. Is it used as a metaphor?
Brace means:

1. a device fitted to something, in particular a weak or injured part of the body, to give support.
2. make (a structure) stronger or firmer with wood, iron, or other forms of support.

Comment: Welcome to the forum. It helps if you do the following:  1) Indicate a quote by using the correct formatting.  Adding  '> '  at the start of every paragraph  will add an indentation. Note that you need a space following the > 2)  Give a longer quote for context.  A sentence before and after the sentence you quote will help. 3) identify the source of the quote. If it comes from an online source, ease add a link.

Comment: It isn't a complete sentence either.

Comment: *Brace* is defined [in the Lexico entry you quote from](https://www.lexico.com/definition/brace) as "3. A pair of something..." which seems apposite in this context. You need to read all senses in the entire definition.

Answer (score 12):

Brace also means 'two' of something,   usually used in the context of game birds.

[example](https://www.tuckersbutchers.com/tuckers-butchers-christmas/tuckers-butchers-christmas-venison-and-game/brace-of-oven-ready-whole-partridge.html): Brace of Oven Ready Whole Partridge

[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/brace) Definition #10

> noun
> 10. a pair; couple:
> *a brace of grouse.*

Sometimes used for humourous effect to mean two of something else.

So it probably means "two men".

Comment: These days, I mostly hear it to mean two goals by the same player in soccer.

Comment: Pete, can I draw your attention to this link concenrning the spelling of 'humorous'? https://oneminuteenglish.org/en/humourous-or-humorous/

Comment: It seems weird to use "brace" this way, when they could say "a couple of able-bodied men".

Comment: @Barmar It's used for effect, two able-bodied men would be even clearer, but the author is presumably not going for clarity, but for metaphor. It's not clear what the context is in such a short extract, but speculating wildly ... A brace of game birds are hunted, taken, shot, against their will. Are these men somehow entering unwillingly into service at home, and will be taken just as one would take a brace of pheasant without considering their humanity (or avianity in the case of birds?)

Comment: @Duckspindle Well, whadayouknow! I might have willing to die on that hill, but the OED (Oxford English Dictionary) agrees with you for humorous whether Brit or US.

Comment: in Tolkien, The Two Towers, chapter Of Herbs and Stewed Rabbit, Frodo asks "What have you stewed?"  then:  A present from Smeagol,' said Sam: `a brace o' young coneys; though I fancy Gollum's regretting them now. But there's nought to go with them but a few herbs.'  In this edition, page 263